# How to import Flask into appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

Getting the lovely error:

```
ERROR    2015-09-23 13:14:12,500 cgi.py:122] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "public/run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src import app
  File "public/src/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I've installed flask into `public/lib` with `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`.

> public/appengine_config.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder
vendor.add('lib')

# also does not work
# import os
# vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

> public/app.yaml

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: src/static

- url: /
  script: run.py
```

> public/run.py

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from src import app

run_wsgi_app(app)
```

> public/src/__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
# import settings

app = Flask('app')
# app.config.from_object('src.settings')

import views
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Starter Project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-flask-skeleton). More importantly, you should change your `app.yaml` to point to the the flask wsgi app.

```
- url: .*
  script: src.app
```

The `run.py` script and `run_wsgi_app()` is the old way to run your app and should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to check out the [gae-init](http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com/) project as it uses Flask and is built on GAE. I found it's a great way to get up and running quickly.